# Wordpress custom form post to send datas to another page

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, post

Hello I'm creating two pages in Wordpress: `dragdrop-translation.php` and `translation-detail.php` using custom template. In the first one the user select a couple of languages, a dead line and the file (.txt or .pdf) that must be traslate. This datas should be send to `traslation-detail` but I've have a problem with the POST action. The template are placed in `wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/dragdrop-translation.php` and `wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/translation-detail.php`

The code of the page that contain the form POST is:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Drag&Drop - Traslation
*
*/
get_header();?>
<div style="margin-top:120px;">
<!--FIRST PART OF FORM-->
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/translation-detail/">
<?php function show_languages_list(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = "wp_languages_price";
    $prepared_query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name."");
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($prepared_query );
    echo '<label for="'.'languages'.'">Select language:</label><select name="'.'languages'.'" id="'.'languages'.'">';
    echo '<option value="" disabled selected>Select languages</option>';
    foreach($results as $languageCouple){
        echo '<option>'.$languageCouple->languages_1.' - '.$languageCouple->languages_2.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
show_languages_list();?>
<label for="start">Deadline:</label>
<input type="date" id="date" name="trip-start"
       min="" max="" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">

<br>
<label>Insert text file</label>
<input type="file" name="datafile" id="datafile" size="40" required>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Calcola preventivo" onclick="checkFields()">
</form>
<br>
<div id="errors" style="color: red;">
</div>
</div>
<script>
    //Script for check the datas removed
</script>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

The code of translation-detail.php is empty so I don't post it.

When I submit the datas, the server replies with a 404 on the action folder of the post.. What path i need to place on the action field of the form?

Comment: _“I'm creating two pages in Wordpress: dragdrop-translation.php and translation-detail.php using custom template.”_ - those are not the “pages” in a WP sense, those are the template files used to _render_ specific pages. So what are the actual URLs (slugs) of your two pages?

Comment: why you want to redirect after first form? and the second thing your action is wrong

Comment: I need two page because i need to calculate the length of the file and show it to the user. I fix the problem.. The path action was wrong.. It should be /index.php/translation-detail/